# Multiple UIButtons positioned horizontally with Auto Layout supported

Tags: ios, uibutton, autolayout

I am working on a UI layout that has five UIButtons positioned one by one horizontally with Auto Layout supported (see below):

```
|                      |
| [b1][b2][b3][b4][b5] |
|                      |
```

Also,

- All the buttons have same widths
- Every adjacent two buttons don't have space between them.
- The leading space of [b1] to its superview is 20.
- The trailing space of [b5] to its superview is 20.

Is it possible to achieve this layout using Interface Builder only? If so, how can I do that? Thanks a lot inadvance.

Comment: i am suggesting you create layout using XIB or storyboard layout. don't do/create programatically layout. i am sure it will help you a lot in future coding structure. You can create Button in the XIB as per your requirements.

Comment: I added the constraints in IB. The basic idea is:

• create leading constraints of b1 to superview's leading
• create Equal Widths constraints for each pair of adjacent buttons
• create horizontal space constraints for each pair of adjacent buttons
• create trailing constraint of b5 to superview's trailing
• create vertical space constraints to Top Layout Guide for each button

After running the app, the result layout is what I really want. Also there is no constraint warning shown in IB or Xcode console window.